# How to prevent fetch() to ignore offline pages?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, fetch-api

The JavaScript code below retrieves some texts from server by using **Fetch** API.

```js
 fetch("index.php?user_id=1234", {
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(output) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    });
```

But during network errors, it retrieves the offline page (offline.html) due to service-worker.

```js
"use strict";

self.addEventListener("install", function() {
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", function(activation) {
    activation.waitUntil(

        caches.keys().then(function(cache_names) {
            for (let cache_name of cache_names) {
                caches.delete(cache_name);
            };

                caches.open("client_cache").then(function(cache) {
                    return cache.add("offline.html");
                });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function(fetching) {
    fetching.respondWith(
        caches.match(fetching.request).then(function(cached_response) {
            return cached_response || fetch(fetching.request);
        }).catch(function() {
            return caches.match("offline.html");
        })
    );
});
```

**I want to let the fetch request know about the network error.**

**And I do not want to use *window.navigator*.** So, what can I do?

*(I prefer vanilla solutions.)*

Comment: Can you add a response header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your service worker's `fetch` event handler so that it only returns `offline.html` when there's a network error/cache miss *and* the original request is for a navigation. If the original request is not a navigation, then responding with `offline.html` is (as you've seen) going to result in getting back HTML for every failure.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then((cachedResponse) => {
      return cachedResponse || fetch(event.request);
    }).catch((error) => {
      if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
        return caches.match('offline.html');
      }

      throw error;
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: This code works as expected. Great!